# Overlapping JLabels in Tetris

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, runnable, tetris

So I'm trying to code Tetris in Java and I'm using JLabels for each piece. I'm using a Runnable timer to have the pieces move down, and then I use if statements with an executor to control when the piece should stop moving.
The problem I have is how I should program the pieces so that when they interact with each other they stop moving down and trigger the executor shutdown. I know that I want to program the block to stop when the color that is a block ahead of it isn't black, signifying that there is a block there, but I need help figuring that out technically.

For Example:

```
Runnable timer = new Runnable() {


public void run() {

        if((825 - (piece.getSize().getHeight() + 40 + piece.getY()) < 1)) { 
            executor.shutdown();
            block();
            time();
        }
        else if(piece2 != null && (825 - (piece2.getSize().getHeight() + 40 + piece2.getY()) < 1)) {
            executor.shutdown();
            block();
            time();
        }
    }   
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer, 2, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

piece2 is referring to the other piece and is only used in shapes where I used to pieces to configure it.

I tried to make a block that tested the color in front of the other block but I had no way of doing that seeing as how I either only tested the background color or the color of the actual block. In which case I would need a way to adapt the block in front of the actual piece to the color that's present whether it be the background or the block, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The keyword is 'custom painting'. Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42518798/131872 for my first attempt at Tetris. It doesn't use a proper model, but it may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Avoid using Swing components to represent a Tetris shape, use lighter-weight image sprites/shapes. There is no reason to use a JLabel, and this only makes your program slower, less responsive, harder to manage and more difficult to enhance.
- Most importantly, the logic of the code should be separate from the GUI. You will want to create a non-GUI component TetrisBlock class that represents one Tetris block and then a TetrisShape class that holds a collection of TetrisBlocks. These should have x and y position fields, which are mutatable. This should also have collision detection by iterating through the collection of TetrisShapes held by your game object. When a collision is detected, then the animation should stop. Collision detection should be fairly easy with this set up since you are looking for collisions on a course granular scale, a block, and not a file scale since there are no real curves, just rectangles.
- The GUI code should instead be updated by the timer to show a representation of the state of the non-GUI model.
- You should be using a Swing Timer to drive the animation rather than a fixed rate executor service with a runnable. This won't solve the original problem but will help prevent future issues with code that currently breaks Swing threading rules.

Comment: swing timer to drive the animation? I'd rather use a real background thread for that, or be it some java Timer. The Swing timer (which runs on the EDT) should be used to render the current state of the animation.

Comment: @queeg Modifying state in a different thread greatly complicates the code, since the code has to be thread-safe (synchronization, Locks, volatile, atomics, etc.).  Unless the animation work is time-consuming, it probably isn’t worth the hassle.

Comment: @queeg: myself, I would use a Swing timer but then would calculate the delta-translation on a real measurement of true delta-time.