# How to ensure that a chess piece is visually removed from the screen after deleting it programmatically in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have implemented a chess game using Java Swing, and I'm facing an issue where even after programmatically deleting a chess piece from the board, its visual representation remains on the screen. I have checked that the data structure holding the pieces is updated correctly, but the visual representation does not reflect this change. How can I ensure that the visual representation of a chess piece is removed from the screen when it is deleted programmatically?

```
public static <K, V> K getKeyFromValue(Map<K, V> map, V value) {
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (Objects.equals(value, entry.getValue())) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

public void deleteChessPiece(ChessPiece piece) {
    if (piece != null) {
        String key = getKeyFromValue(pieceBox, piece);
        if (key != null) {
            System.out.println(key);
            pieceBox.remove(key);
            pieceLabels.remove(key);
            JLabel label = pieceLabels.get(key);
            if (label != null) {
                remove(label); 
            }
        }
    }
    invalidate();
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

And :

```
package com.wallhack.chess;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Board extends JPanel {
    private final PieceFactory pieceFactory = new PieceFactory();
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, ChessPiece> pieceBox = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public HashMap<String, JLabel> pieceLabels = new HashMap<>();
    private final int cellSize = 80;
    private final int initialX = 63;
    private final int initialY = 60;
    private final BoardRender boardRender;
    private final BoardLayoutManager boardLayoutManager;
    private Point highlightCell;

    public Board(BoardLayoutManager boardLayoutManager) {
        this.boardLayoutManager = boardLayoutManager;
        setLayout(new BoardLayoutManager());

        boardRender = new BoardRender(initialX, initialY, cellSize);

        pieceByDefault();

        for (String piece : pieceBox.keySet()) {
            createAndPositionLabel(piece);
        }

        for (String piece : pieceLabels.keySet()) {
            JLabel label = pieceLabels.get(piece);
            ChessPiece chessPiece = pieceBox.get(piece);
            if (label != null && chessPiece != null) {
                Point pieceCoordinates = new Point(chessPiece.getCoordinates().x, chessPiece.getCoordinates().y);
                add(label , pieceCoordinates);
            }
        }


        MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler(this, new PieceMoves(this));
        addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);

    }
    public static <K, V> K getKeyFromValue(Map<K, V> map, V value) {
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (Objects.equals(value, entry.getValue())) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        boardRender.drawBoard(g2);
        boardRender.drawLabel(g2);

        if (highlightCell != null) {
            Point cell = gridToPoint(highlightCell);
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(cell.x, cell.y, cellSize,cellSize);
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.draw(bounds);
        }
    }

    private void createAndPositionLabel(String piece) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        try {
            String imagePath = "com/wallhack/chess/resources/" + pieceBox.get(piece).getIndex();
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(imagePath)))));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Eroare la citirea imaginii!");
        }

        Point offset = getBoardOffset();
        Point pieceCoordinates = gridToPoint(pieceBox.get(piece).getCoordinates());
        label.setBounds(pieceCoordinates.x + offset.x, pieceCoordinates.y + offset.y, cellSize, cellSize);

        pieceLabels.put(piece, label);
    }

    private void pieceByDefault () {
        String[][] defaultPositions = {
                {"Br1", "Bn1", "Bb1", "Bq", "Bk", "Bb2", "Bn2", "Br2"},
                {"Bp1", "Bp2", "Bp3", "Bp4", "Bp5", "Bp6", "Bp7", "Bp8"},
                {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
                {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
                {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
                {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
                {"LP1", "LP2", "LP3", "LP4", "LP5", "LP6", "LP7", "LP8"},
                {"LR1", "LN1", "LB1", "LQ", "LK", "LB2", "LN2", "LR2"}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < defaultPositions.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < defaultPositions.length; j++) {
                String pieceType = defaultPositions[i][j];
                if (!pieceType.equals(" ")) {
                    pieceBox.put(pieceType, pieceFactory.create(pieceType.charAt(1), new Point(j, i)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Point pointToGrid(Point p) {
        Point point = null;
        if (p != null) {
            var pointX = (p.x - initialX) / cellSize;
            var pointY = (p.y - initialY) / cellSize;
            if (0 <= pointX && pointX <= 7 && 0 <= pointY && pointY <= 7){
                point = new Point(pointX, pointY);
            }
        }
        return point;
    }
    public Point gridToPoint(Point grid) {
        Point p = new Point();
        if (grid != null) {
            p.x = grid.x * cellSize + initialX;
            p.y = grid.y * cellSize + initialY;
        }
        return p;
    }

    public void setPieceGrid(Component comp, Point grid) {
        ((BoardLayoutManager) getLayout()).setPieceGrid(comp, grid);
        invalidate();
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

//    public void deleteChessPiece(ChessPiece piece) {
//        if (piece != null) {
//            String key = getKeyFromValue(pieceBox, piece);
//            if (key != null) {
//                System.out.println(key);
//                pieceBox.remove(key);
//                pieceLabels.remove(key);
//                JLabel label = pieceLabels.get(key);
//                if (label != null) {
//                    remove(label);
//                }
//            }
//        }
//        invalidate();
//        revalidate();
//        repaint();
//    }
public void deleteChessPiece(ChessPiece piece) {
    if (piece != null) {
        String key = getKeyFromValue(pieceBox, piece);
        if (key != null) {
            System.out.println(key);
            pieceBox.remove(key);
            pieceLabels.remove(key);
            JLabel label = pieceLabels.get(key);
            if (label != null) {
                remove(label);
            }
        }
    }
    invalidate();
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}


    protected Point getBoardOffset() {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        Point p = new Point();
        p.x = (width - (cellSize * 8)) / 2;
        p.y = (height - (cellSize * 8)) / 2;

        return p;
    }
    public ChessPiece getPieceAt(Point coordinates){
        ChessPiece myPiece = null;

        for (ChessPiece piece : pieceBox.values()){
            if (piece.getCoordinates().x == coordinates.x && coordinates.y == piece.getCoordinates().y){
                myPiece = piece;
            }
        }
        return myPiece;
    }


    public void setHightlightCell(Point p) {
        if (highlightCell != p) {
            highlightCell = p;
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    private Component dragComponent;
    public static Component d;
    private final Board board;
    private final PieceMoves pieceMoves;
    private Point dragOffset;
    public static final boolean SNAP_TO_GRID = false;
    private Point dragOffsetToPoint;

    public MouseHandler(Board board, PieceMoves pieceMoves) {
        this.board = board;
        this.pieceMoves = pieceMoves;
    }

    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Component comp = getBoard().getComponentAt(e.getPoint());

        if (comp != null) {
            dragComponent = comp;
            dragOffset = new Point();
            dragOffset.x = e.getPoint().x - comp.getX();
            dragOffset.y = e.getPoint().y - comp.getY();

            dragOffsetToPoint = getBoard().pointToGrid(comp.getLocation());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (dragComponent != null) {
            getBoard().setEnabled(true);
            Board board = getBoard();
            Point p = board.pointToGrid(e.getPoint());
            ChessPiece piece = board.getPieceAt(dragOffsetToPoint);

            if (p != null && pieceMoves.isAllowed(piece, p, dragOffsetToPoint)){
                ChessPiece piece1= board.getPieceAt(p);
                d = getBoard().getComponentAt(p);
                if (d != null) {
                    board.deleteChessPiece(piece1);
                }

                piece.getCoordinates().setLocation(p);
                board.setPieceGrid(dragComponent, p);
            } else {
                board.setPieceGrid(dragComponent, dragOffsetToPoint);
                piece.getCoordinates().setLocation(dragOffsetToPoint);
            }

            dragComponent = null;
            board.setHightlightCell(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (dragComponent != null) {
            Board board = getBoard();
            Point grid = board.pointToGrid(e.getPoint());
            if (SNAP_TO_GRID) {
                Point p = board.gridToPoint(grid);
                dragComponent.setLocation(p);
            } else {
                Point dragPoint = new Point();
                dragPoint.x = e.getPoint().x - dragOffset.x;
                dragPoint.y = e.getPoint().y - dragOffset.y;

                dragComponent.setLocation(dragPoint);
            }
            board.setHightlightCell(grid);
        }
    }
}
public class PieceMoves {
    private final Board board;

    public PieceMoves(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    private boolean isPathClear(Point coord, Point initial) {
        int deltaX = coord.x - initial.x;
        int deltaY = coord.y - initial.y;

        for (int i = 1; i < Math.max(Math.abs(deltaX), Math.abs(deltaY)); i++) {
            int x = initial.x + i * Integer.compare(deltaX, 0);
            int y = initial.y + i * Integer.compare(deltaY, 0);

            if (board.getPieceAt(new Point(x, y)) != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isDiagonalClear(Point coord, Point initial) {
        int deltaX = coord.x - initial.x;
        int deltaY = coord.y - initial.y;

        int dirX = Integer.compare(deltaX, 0);
        int dirY = Integer.compare(deltaY, 0);

        for (int i = 1; i < Math.max(Math.abs(deltaX), Math.abs(deltaY)); i++) {
            int x = initial.x + dirX * i;
            int y = initial.y + dirY * i;

            if (board.getPieceAt(new Point(x, y)) != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private boolean isValidPawnMove(Point coord, Point initial) {
        ChessPiece piece = board.getPieceAt(coord);
        ChessPiece initialPiece = board.getPieceAt(initial);

        var validation = false;
        int deltaX = initial.x - coord.x;
        int deltaY = initial.y - coord.y;

        if (piece == null) {

            if (initialPiece.getPlayer() == ChessPiece.Player.White){
                if ((deltaY == 1 || deltaY == 2) && coord.x == initial.x) {
                    validation = true;
                }
            } else if (initialPiece.getPlayer() == ChessPiece.Player.Black) {
                if ((deltaY == -1 || deltaY == -2) && coord.x == initial.x) {
                    validation = true;
                }
            }

        } else if (piece.getPlayer() != initialPiece.getPlayer()) {
            if (initialPiece.getPlayer() == ChessPiece.Player.White) {
                if (deltaY == 1 && deltaX == 1 || deltaY == 1 && deltaX == -1) {
                    validation = true;
                }
            }else if (initialPiece.getPlayer() == ChessPiece.Player.Black) {
                if (deltaY == -1 && deltaX == -1 || deltaY == -1 && deltaX == 1) {
                    validation = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return validation;
    }


    private boolean isValidKnightMove(Point coord, Point initial) {
        ChessPiece piece = board.getPieceAt(coord);
        ChessPiece initialPiece = board.getPieceAt(initial);
        var validation = false;

        if (piece == null || piece.getPlayer() != initialPiece.getPlayer()){
            var deltaX = initial.x - coord.x;
            var deltaY = initial.y - coord.y;

            if (Math.abs(deltaX) == 2 && Math.abs(deltaY) == 1){
                validation = true;
            }else validation = Math.abs(deltaX) == 1 && Math.abs(deltaY) == 2;
        }
        return validation;
    }

    private boolean isValidRookMove(Point coord, Point initial) {
        ChessPiece piece = board.getPieceAt(coord);
        ChessPiece initialPiece = board.getPieceAt(initial);
        boolean validation = false;

        if (piece == null || piece.getPlayer() != initialPiece.getPlayer()) {
            if (coord.x == initial.x || coord.y == initial.y) {
                if (isPathClear(initial, coord)) {
                    validation = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return validation;
    }


    private boolean isValidBishopMove(Point coord, Point initial) {
        ChessPiece piece = board.getPieceAt(coord);
        ChessPiece initialPiece = board.getPieceAt(initial);
        boolean validation = false;

        if (piece == null || piece.getPlayer() != initialPiece.getPlayer()) {
            if (Math.abs(coord.x - initial.x) == Math.abs(coord.y - initial.y)) {
                if (isDiagonalClear(initial, coord)) {
                    validation = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return validation;
    }


    private boolean isValidQueenMove(Point coord, Point initial) {
        return isValidBishopMove(coord , initial) || isValidRookMove(coord , initial);
    }

    private boolean isValidKingMove(Point coord, Point initial) {
        ChessPiece piece = board.getPieceAt(coord);
        ChessPiece initialPiece = board.getPieceAt(initial);
        var validation = false;

        if (piece == null || piece.getPlayer() != initialPiece.getPlayer()){
            var deltaX = Math.abs(initial.x - coord.x);
            var deltaY = Math.abs(initial.y - coord.y);

            if (deltaX == 1 && deltaY == 0){
                validation = true;
            }else if (deltaX == 0 && deltaY == 1) validation = true;
            else if (deltaX == 1 && deltaY == 1) validation = true;
        }
        return validation;
    }


    public boolean isAllowed(ChessPiece piece,Point coord, Point initial) {

        System.out.println(piece.getCoordinates());

        return switch (piece.getRank()) {
            case Pawn -> isValidPawnMove(coord, initial);
            case Knight -> isValidKnightMove(coord,initial);
            case Bishop -> isValidBishopMove(coord , initial);
            case Rook -> isValidRookMove(coord, initial);
            case Queen -> isValidQueenMove(coord, initial);
            case King -> isValidKingMove(coord, initial);
        };
    }
}
```

I tried removing the JLabel associated with the deleted chess piece from the JPanel using the remove method, but the visual representation of the piece still remained on the screen. I expected that by removing the JLabel, the visual representation of the chess piece would also be removed from the screen.

Comment: *I tried removing the JLabel associated with the deleted chess piece from the JPanel* - the invalidate() is not needed. In Swing you use `revalidate()` to invoke the layout manager and then `repaint()` to make sure the panel is repainted if the layout changes. You appear to be doing this. How do you know the label is removed from the panel? It seems to me the "label" variable would be null, since you remove the piece from the "pieceLabels" first.

Comment: If you remove a label from the Swing hierarchy, why should the label variable be null? It won't be unless you set it to null or run out of the variable's scope.

Comment: You’re better off using an array of `ChessPiece` objects in the first place, instead of using strings and mapping from string to piece all the time. And when you have it, implement a simple `TableModel` with 8 rows and 8 columns and use a `JTable` (with fixed cell size and without a scroll pane). This provides you with all things you’re trying to implement manually, a layout, mapping between screen coordinates and cells, even drag&drop support. In this approach, you’re not removing pieces, you change a cell value from “piece xyz” to “empty”. Which is far simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you camickr. I tried to remove null references :D

Corrected code:

```java
public void deleteChessPiece(ChessPiece piece) {
    if (piece != null) {
        String key = getKeyFromValue(pieceBox, piece);
        if (key != null) {
            JLabel label = pieceLabels.get(key);
            if (label != null) {
                remove(label);
            }
            pieceBox.remove(key);
            pieceLabels.remove(key);
        }
    }
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For games you'd typically not use Swing Components at all, but instead go for custom painting. It allows way better control of positioning the elements you need. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.

Once you are there, removing an element would just mean to remove it from the model and rerender the model, which would draw everything except the removed element.

Also look at the recommendation how to create Tetris in Java Swing:
[Overlapping JLabels in Tetris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137071/overlapping-jlabels-in-tetris/78137101#comment137757895_78137101)